# View HTML file in zip acrhive from an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, zip

Is it possible to view the index.html file from a .zip archive using an iframe in HTML? Or does it exist some JS library that can do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stuk.github.io/jszip/

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you have js, css, or image files in your archive? I can't figure out how to route those so they won't be a 404.

Comment: No sorry, there where just an index.html file. I didnt really get a hand on it though, I got it working somehow with the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just wanted to elaborate further the @Vohuman's comment because I think it's important.

From what I understand by the documentation of `jszip` library it can be done.

1. Read the zip file (by using `JSZipUtils)`

```js
JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent('path/to/content.zip', function(err, data) {
  if(err) {
    throw err; // or handle err
  }

  var zip = new JSZip(data);
});
```

Source: https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/howto/read_zip.html

2. Read it using:

```js
var new_zip = new JSZip();
// more files !
new_zip.load(content);

// you now have every files contained in the loaded zip
new_zip.file("hello.txt").asText(); // "Hello World\n"
```

Source: https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/examples.html (Scroll the bottom of the page (`Read a zip file` section))

3. Finally, create an iframe and put the `html` content into it.

```js
$('#your_iframe').contents().find('html').html(htmlZipContent);
```

Comment: This was the more explained answer, so you get the checkmark.
I read the documentation on JSZip, saw that it could load files from .zip as plain text. Didn't think of using `.html()`. Thank you!